# Highlighting the values between the two given data

Tags: jquery

I have a php generated scale table from 1 to 14. I highlight the min and max values given by the checkbox form on the table with the following jquery code.

Sample table:

```js
$("#checkAll").click(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)
    .trigger("change");
});

$(".selector").on("change", function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest("form");

  $("#" + parent.data("checktable"))
    .find('[dbval="' + this.name + '"]')
    .toggleClass("highlight", $(this).is(":checked"));
  parent
    .find(".all")
    .prop(
      "checked",
      parent.find(".selector:checked").length === parent.find(".selector").length
    );
});

$(".all").on("change", function() {
  $(this).closest("form").find(".selector")
    .prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"))
    .trigger("change");
});

$(".all:checked").each(function() {
  $(this).closest("form").find(".selector").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
});

$(".selector").trigger("change");
```

```css
table.tbA {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table.tbA td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  text-align: center;
}

table.tbA th {
  background-color: #104E8B;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlight {
  background: #9ac99d;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='tbA' id='tb32'>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='14'>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='13'>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='12'>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='11'>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='10'>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='9'>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='8'>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='7'>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='6'>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='5'>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='4'>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='3'>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='2'>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='1'>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="CheckAll" id="checkAll" class="all"> All </label>

<form id='form32' data-checktable='tb32' name='form32' method='post' action=' '>
  <label>
            <input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='SelectAll' class='all'>All</label>
  <label>
            <input type='checkbox' class='selector' name='4'>4</label>
  <label>
            <input type='checkbox' class='selector' name='6'>6</label>
</form>
<form id='form31' data-checktable='tb31' name='form31' method='post' action=' '>
  <label>
            <input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='SelectAll' class='all'>All</label>
  <label>
            <input type='checkbox' class='selector' name='3'>3</label>
  <label>
            <input type='checkbox' class='selector' name='12'>12</label>
</form>
```

Normally I mostly have two values (min and max), but sometimes  there happens to be a single value (either min or max) to be highlighted, or no values at all (no highlight).
 I need to highlight not only the min and max values but all the values between the minimum and maximum values.

For example if (min,max) is (2,8), then `2,3,4,5,6,7, and 8` should be highlighted. How can I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having a `value=` and instead using `name='3'` type things on the check boxes is just odd but I deal with that.

In order to get a range, you need the min and max and then select those values equal or between those.  If only one is checked, it is both min and max.  IF there are three check boxes in a group (not here but possible) the same logic works.

So basically it comes down to selecting the values in the target table that match the range.

NOTE: This code is VERY verbose so you can see what is going on and can be compacted a bit.

I would have used `data-myvalue` type attributes instead of `dbval=` in the table and `name=` on check boxes for a variety of reasons, but it's not my work here.

`if (!!t.length) {` protects against the case where the table does not exist (like the second set of check boxes)

```js
$("#checkAll").on('change', function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox].all')
    .not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)
    .trigger("change");
});

$(".selector").on("change", function() {
  var myForm = $(this).closest("form");
  let t = $("#" + myForm.data("checktable"));
  if (!!t.length) {
    let tList = t.find('[dbval]');
    tList.toggleClass("highlight", false);
    let checks = myForm.find("input[type=checkbox].selector");
    let checkedList = checks.filter(':checked');
    myForm.find('.all')
      .prop('checked', (checks.length === checkedList.length));
    let selectedValues = [];
    checkedList
      .each(function(index, element) {
        selectedValues.push($(element).attr("name") * 1); //why not value??
      });
    let max = Math.max(...selectedValues);
    let min = Math.min(...selectedValues);
    let listThings = tList.filter(function(index) {
      let v = $(this).attr("dbval") * 1;
      return (v <= max && v >= min);
    }).toggleClass("highlight", !!checkedList.length);
  }
});


$("input[type=checkbox].all").on("change", function() {
    $(this).closest("form")
      .find(".selector")
      .prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"))
      .trigger("change");
  })
  .trigger("change")
  .parent().css('border', 'solid 1px blue'); // just to show
```

```css
table.tbA {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table.tbA td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  text-align: center;
}

table.tbA th {
  background-color: #104E8B;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlight {
  background: #9ac99d;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='tbA' id='tb32'>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='14'>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='13'>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='12'>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='11'>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='10'>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='9'>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='8'>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='7'>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='6'>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='5'>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='4'>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='3'>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='2'>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td dbval='1'>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="CheckAll" id="checkAll" class="all"> All </label>

<form id='form32' data-checktable='tb32' name='form32' method='post' action=' '>
  <label><input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='SelectAll' class='all'>All</label><label><input type='checkbox' class='selector' name='4'>4</label><label><input type='checkbox' class='selector' name='6'>6</label></form>
<form id='form31' data-checktable='tb31' name='form31' method='post' action=' '><label><input type='checkbox' checked='checked' name='SelectAll' class='all'>All</label><label><input type='checkbox' class='selector' name='3'>3</label><label><input type='checkbox' class='selector' name='12'>12</label></form>
```